# Displaying fullcalendar events (from gcal) in their original timezone

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to render events from several Google Calendars. Each calendar represents events at a specific location, and I want to display all events in the original timezones, regardless of the client's location.

For example: an event starting at 8am in Tokyo should display at 8am for everyone, everywhere (the calendar on the page is labelled as being relevant to Tokyo).

Currently by default, all events are being converted into the client's local timezone - here in London my 8am Tokyo event is shown as starting at 11pm.

The only way I've managed to display the events in the original timezone is to explicitly initialise each calendar with the corresponding TZ string for the `timezone` option, but it feels wrong having to go to this length, since the timezone must already be known.

Is this expected behaviour, or is there a problem with the calendar events themselves?

Comment: If you want to view date time info in location A originating from location B and localized to B's time zone. Then you will need to know the time zone info for location B to perform the translation.

Comment: @RossBush I get that, but I don't want to localize anything. The time zone as it was originally created in Google Calendar should be the one that is displayed. I'm getting localization currently but I don't want any, and I don't think I should have to specify the original event timezone in order to display it in that zone?

Comment: I bet that date time is stored as UTC time. The only magic occurs when you translate to the clients representation of UTC. You need to simply show in Tokyo's UTC representation.

Comment: @RossBush you could be right - I'm trying to get hold of access to the calendar to check.

Comment: @RossBush your suspicions were correct - the Google Calendar time zone setting itself on each calendar was set to UTC.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can define timezone on event `start` and `end` params. Like

`{ title: "event1", start: "2013-10-20T02:00:00+09:00" }`

Where `+09:00` sates the time zone. For more: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

if you are fetching events from google calendar then you can prepare your events so that it contains the timezone like

```
              ...............
                $single_event['event_id'] = $event['id'];
                $single_event['title'] = $event['summary']; ´
                $single_event['start'] = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // change here
                $single_event['time'] = $date->format('H:i');
                $single_event['endtime'] = $enddate->format('H:i');

                array_push($event_list, $single_event);
                ...............
```

if you use google credentials directly to fullcalendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Then just check your google calendar timezone settings.

Comment: I'm not creating or fetching events through the API manually - I'm using the Google Calendar extension to fetch all events from a specific Google Calendar ID. The events are added directly to Google Calendar (with the timezones specified at that time). I'm just looking to display all events in that original timezone.

Comment: okay, then I need to know how are you facing events from google calendar. are you getting events using php?

Comment: @bbodien, I tried to make it more clear. have a look now.

Comment: I'm not using PHP or any back-end, it's just the Google Calendar extension https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ - I think the problem might be with how the events were created, or the timezone setting of the calendar itself. I'm trying to get access to check.

Comment: then it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Google Calendar timezone setting was incorrect. Once this was changed on each calendar being used as a source, the events showed up in the correct timezone for each regional calendar.

Comment: then still you can accept my answer to help the community because that contains all related information and also helped you to find your problem :)